# Can't initialize float array with {0}

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, runtime-error

My Compiler gives runtime error when I initialize the float array in Veccreator function. I am here posting just a sample of what my code looks like.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
#define SIZE 1000
class Vector
{
private:
    float vecarray[SIZE];
public:
    void VecCreator(int dimension)
    {
        vecarray[SIZE]= { 0 };
        cout << "Enter " << dimension << " digits" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
        {
            cin >> vecarray[i];
        }
    }


};
int main(void) {
    Vector obh;
    obh.VecCreator(2);
}
```

But it works fine with this:`

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
#define SIZE 1000
class Vector
{
private:
    float vecarray[SIZE]= {0};
public:
    void VecCreator(int dimension)
    {
        cout << "Enter " << dimension << " digits" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
        {
            cin >> vecarray[i];
        }
    }


};
int main(void) {
    Vector obh;
    obh.VecCreator(2);
}
```

Please tell me why the first code is giving error.

Comment: Search for and read about *constructor initializer lists*.

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: This is a buffer overrun. In C, array indices are zero-based. You expression `vecarray[SIZE] = 0` assigns a value past the last index of the array, which is SIZE-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the second answer here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/14e7318e-6fff-4d68-a823-9cbe7b7bc20a/debugging-runtime-check-failure-2-stack-around-the-variable-loggerthread-was-corrupted?forum=vcgeneral

why not do it like here below? i mean if you want to put values in there, why initially put 0 in there?

```
private:
    float vecarray[SIZE];
public:
    void VecCreator(int dimension)
    {
        cout << "Enter " << dimension << " digits" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
        {
            cin >> vecarray[i];
        }
    }
```